# ScrollViewer горизонтальная прокрутка

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Как сделать чтобы при наведении на содержимое ScrollViewer можно было пользоваться колесиком мышки для прокрутки?

```
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Grid Width="300" Height="50" Background="Blue"></Grid>
                    <Grid Width="300" Height="50" Background="Black"></Grid>
                    <Grid Width="300" Height="50" Background="Orange"></Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              PreviewMouseWheel="ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Grid Width="300" Height="50" Background="Blue"></Grid>
        <Grid Width="300" Height="50" Background="Black"></Grid>
        <Grid Width="300" Height="50" Background="Orange"></Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>

private void ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    ScrollViewer scrollviewer= sender as ScrollViewer;
    if (e.Delta > 0)
        scrollviewer.LineLeft();
    else
        scrollviewer.LineRight();
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Хм, не знал. +1.